# Connection String in to access using oracle syntax

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

Is there any way i can connect to my access database using C# and process oracle syntax querys?

my connection string now is :

```
 string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='|DataDirectory|\DataBase.accdb';Persist Security Info=True";
```

And the syntax there is sql server

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP.NET) is an implementation of a .NET data provider for Oracle Database. It uses Oracle native APIs to offer fast and reliable access to Oracle data and features from any .NET application. Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP.NET) features optimized ADO.NET data access to the Oracle database. ODP.NET allows developers to take advantage of advanced Oracle database functionality, including Real Application Clusters, XML DB, and advanced security.

Sample Code

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
OracleConnection myConnection = new OracleConnection();
myConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
myConnection.Open();
//execute queries 
myConnection.Close();
```

TNS

Syntax:

```
Data Source=TORCL;User Id=urUsername;Password=urPassword;
Integrated Security
```

Syntax:

```
Data Source=TORCL;Integrated Security=SSPI;
Privileged Connections
```

Syntax:

```
Data Source=urOracle;User Id=urUsername;Password=urPassword;DBA Privilege=SYSDBA;
```

Runtime Connection Load Balancing
Syntax:

```
Data Source=urOracle;User Id=urUsername;Password=urPassword;Load Balancing=True;
```

Connect Naming Method to connect to an Instance
Syntax:

```
Data Source=username/password@urserver//instancename;
```

Connect Naming Method for connecting to a dedicated server instance
Syntax:

```
Data Source=username/password@urserver/urservice:dedicated/instancename;
```

Applying ODP.NET without tnsnames.ora
Syntax:

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=urHost)(PORT=urPort)))
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=urOracleSID)));User Id=urUsername;
Password=urPassword;
```

Applying the Easy Connect Naming Method (aka EZ Connect)
Syntax:

```
Data Source=username/password@//urserver:1433/ur.service.com;
```

Windows user authentication
Syntax:

```
Data Source=urOracle;User Id=/;
```

Specification of Pooling parameters
Syntax:

```
Data Source=urOracle;User Id=urUsername;Password=urPassword;Min Pool Size=10;Connection Lifetime=180;Connection Timeout=60;Incr Pool Size8;Decr Pool Size=5;
```

Restricting Pool size
Syntax:

```
Data Source=urOracle;User Id=urUsername;Password=urPassword;Max Pool Size=50;Connection Timeout=60;
```

Disable Pooling
Syntax:

```
Data Source=urOracle;User Id=urUsername;Password=urPassword;Pooling=False;
```